# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input in simple html javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My html page looks like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>

function changeColorAndSize(){
{
    document.getElementById('demo').style.color='red'
    document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize='100px'
}
</script>

<h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>

<p id="demo">JavaScript can change the style of an HTML element.</p>

<button onclick="changeColorAndSize()">Click Me!</button>


</body>
</html>
```

but it fails with error 
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input**

Please advise what is wrong with this code? I tried looking into w3schools but still no luck.

Comment: You have 2 `{` after `function changeColorAndSize()`

Answer (score 0):

This is where the issue occurs.
I changed it from

```
function changeColorAndSize(){
{
    document.getElementById('demo').style.color='red'
    document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize='100px'
}
```

to

```
function changeColorAndSize()
{
    document.getElementById('demo').style.color='red'
    document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize='100px'
}
```

because you have an extra `{`, which causes the error.

```js
function changeColorAndSize(){
    document.getElementById('demo').style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize = '100px';
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>
    <p id="demo">JavaScript can change the style of an HTML element.</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="changeColorAndSize()">Click Me!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```